# Run tasks in background per user

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I'm making a homepage where I can have organized all my bookmarks, take notes, a calendar, add things to a wishlist, etc. One of the things I would like it's to synchronize my email accounts with it, I saw that I can use [mailkit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) for that. I'm planning that, let's say, every five minutes, the app fetch the emails to know how many unread emails there are. But I'm facing some problems:

With this [guide](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html) I saw that I can run a scheduled task, so I can use it like a cron job, but the problem is that that task is generic for all users and I can't just fetch the emails for the user connected.

A solution I thought was to let jQuery make requests to an api through ajax with a timer to run it every five minutes, but if I have the web open in two tabs, I'm doing the request for each tab overloading the server.

What can I do or what is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IHostedService should be generic, i.e. you wouldn't have one per user, just one capable of handling multiple users. To begin monitoring a particular user, you would simply "subscribe" them in some way. That could be as simple as adding something to a database which your background service would check or you could use something like a message queue. In either case, your background service would check this store to see which users it needs to fetch info for, and then just process them one by one.

Comment: I like that solution, it's simple and effective. I can just add a field 'logged' in the user table. Thanks